# Couldn't find User without an ID - Ruby 2.1.4 / Rails 4.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, parameters

I am facing an error while trying to link the `:username` in my `User` table and my `Room` table. I made a custom auth with devise and added `:username`.

I would like the `username` to be the link between the `User` table from devise and my `Room` table.

I am trying to build this app to recreate a kind of airbnb but mainly as an exercise as I started programming in ruby few months ago.

I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RoomsController#new
Couldn't find User without an ID
line #19 @room.username = User.find(params[:username])
```

Thank you very much for your help. I am stuck in here for hours now :-(

**rooms_controller**

```
def new
  @room = Room.new
  @room.username = User.find(params[:username]) #error seems to come from here
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get "home/info"

  root :to => "home#info"

  resources :rooms

  resources :users do
  resources :rooms
end
```

**room.rb**

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :username, :location, :description, :capacity, :price_day, :photo
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  has_many :rooms
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this

```
def new
  @room = Room.new
  @room.username = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

If you just use .find() it expects the id of the user. Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders

Comment: I think the OP is new to RoR. You should update your answer with possible variations as well: i.e.`find_by(conditions)` and `where(conditions).last`

Comment: I don't think that an answer should include a copy of the rails documentation. That's why a included a link. He is definitely new to rails and also what he tries to do doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, but in order to help with that he would need to update his question

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic error in that you are saving @room.username to the User Object. You should be setting @room.user = User.find_by(...) OR @room.user_id = User.find_by(...).id

Active record will automagically make a method for you that will be @room.user.username if you want to get the username.

Now, here are the ways to find a user.

```
@room = Room.new #Then either of the following

@room.user = User.find_by(username: params[:username]) #Returns only one value

@room.user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])  #Returns only one value

@room.user = User.where(username: params[:username])   #Returns all users which meet condition.
```

As already mentioned in the answers, User.find() takes an ID. One thing to know is that all methods that start with .find for active record return a single record even if many meet the condition.

If you are having any problems still, then show us your Database Schema, and we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The Room is created with the the right :username and nothing is seen by the user.
In my Rooms controller, I kept

```
def new
@room = Room.new end
```

And I added this line in the "def create" part :

```
def create
@room = Room.new(room_params)
@room.username = current_user.username
```

Thank you for your help, this help me to understand better the relations in rails.

Have a nice day !